# Django save method on a form - update one to one model relate

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

I'm trying to create an app with a password policy: must be at least 8 characters long and they will have an expiration date.

I created a class in forms.py extending the SetPasswordForm that let me set a minimun password length.

For the expiration date, I created a model named bUser that is related OneToOne to the user model of django.auth.contrib.

In this model (bUser) I wanted to save the last time that the password was changed, so I tried to edit the save method of my form in order to update the field everytime the password was changed.

**forms.py**

```
class SetPasswordWithMinLengthForm(SetPasswordForm):
    min_password_length = 8

    def clean_new_password1(self):
        " Minimum length "
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1', '')
        if len(password1) < self.min_password_length:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password must have at least %i characters" % self.min_password_length)
        else:
            return password1

    def save(self,commit = True):
        new_pass = super(SetPasswordWithMinLengthForm, self).save(commit = False)
        if commit:
            new_pass.save()
            usr = bUser.objects.get(user=new_pass)
            if usr:
                usr.last_pass_set_on = date.today
                usr.save()
        return new_pass
```

**models.py**

```
class bUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    last_pass_set_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The problem is that when I try to change the password of a user, I get the following error

```
TypeError at /password/change/
expected string or buffer
```

Specifically, in the line where I save the update on the bUser instance. If I comment this line, it works (but of course, it doesn't change the value on the bUser model)

```
usr.save()
```

I tried printing in the console by using "print(usr.last_pass_set_on)", and it is printed correctly.

Can I update a related instance in the save method of a form?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: date.today is a function so try date.today()

Comment: Of course, BogdiG! So embarrased... it was very late :p
If you want, please answer the question and I'll select your answer